# Where did the WindowsSymbolicLink folder come from?

Tags: windows-7, links

I've only recently become aware of symbolic links, and now I have some understanding.
But my interest was stimulated by finding a folder on my 'Documents' drive - which is just d:\ in my case.
The folder's name is WindowsSymbolicLinks.  It occupies 26 GB and contains sub-folders which look to relate to probably every one of my applications.
Can anybody tell me where it came from, and what is does, please?
I presume I can't get rid of it?

Comment: I have symbolic links on my Windows 7 computer, but I can't find any reference to that folder on my computer or on Google. Can you provide any further information?

Comment: The folder doesn't contain any symbolic links that I can recognise by using tools such as NTFSLinksView or Junction Magic.  Under each subfolder there is a structure - so that under the Microsoft sub-folder there are 36 sub-sub-folders, including Outlook, Word etc.but also Clip Organiser, Signatures, Speech, UProof, and others that don't mean anything to me.  I don't know if these were all created in one go, or whether the folder has been gradually increasing over the months. The Word data includes asd, wbk and tmp files.  Outlook contains srs and xml files.  Excel contains lots of xar files.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but is it possible that you or someone else created this folder and then created symbolic links to it? This seems like something someone might have done to clear space on the OS partition. This looks like data from the `%APPDATA%` folder. Try running this command in the command prompt: `dir /al /s "%APPDATA%\.."`

Comment: Hi Worthwelle. Thanks for your interest.  More clues are (1) My age and memory are such that I can't rule out your 'stupid question', but (2) I've analysed my machine and find no links on my c:\ drive which point to the folder. (3) I rarely/never create folders with names which have no spaces between words. (4) I bought an SSD about a year ago and followed several articles advising on best use of them. (5) I've been toying with two Start Menus - Classic Shell and Open-Shell, which have created work around this area.(6) The timestamps on the sub-folders are mainly in 2 large 'clumps'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am crawling to an answer.  Could anyone explain this, please?

I have scanned my whole machine for symlinks, using Junction Link Magic, and my c:\ drive with NTFS Links View.  These were consistent in indicating only one symbolic link pointing to a drive other than my c:\ drive. (Most were apparently generated by Windows, which I understand).  The external link was not to the problem folder d:\WindowsSymbolicLinks.
But if I type %AppData% into the address line of My Computer it is immediately replaced by "d:\WindowsSymbolicLinks".
I've checked the properties of all of the AppData folders under c:\Users, and none have been relocated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite close now.  By tracking down the location of %appdata% I arrived at this page
https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/envivari.htm
This tells me how to see all environment variables and their values.
I found the following definition:  %appdata%=d:\WindowsSymbolicLinks.
So I know what's causing the situation.  Now I just need to understand how Windows uses environment variables, and the I'll be in control!